# mysql aurora high innodb_buffer_pool_reads on a write heavy db instance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-aurora

i have a weird problem in with my aurora cluster.
the cluster have two instances, with 4 cores and 32GB spec, writer and reader instance.

currently its pushing about 2000 INSERT/second with 0.5KB row size to a table that is about 100GB size with 100GB secondary indexes, PK is bigint autoincrement.
current row count is about 1Billion+

as the table size grow i notice theres some significant amount of innodb buffer pool IO, which i don't understand why it could happen?
i understand that due to the table index size it can't fit everything into the memory, but still with the amount of disk IO hits, logically its not possible?

is there any reason there  is a "read" into the buffer pool memory/disk when all i did is just inserting into that table?

so i did perform a table swap (rename the big table to _old and then recreate the table), the problem goes away but then after few days it returned.

also, currently using the golang to do the inserts but for some reason it always append this "START TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT" statement even though its just a single insert statement, but not sure if this impacts anything